# Setting the SQL connection string for ASP.NET Core web app in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, connection-string

I have created a new ASP.NET Core web application in Visual Studio 2015. I've also set up an Azure web app to pull in the app from GitHub and run it. This works fine, but I'm having trouble connecting to the database on Azure.

Locally, this works, and it uses `config.json` and in code `Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString` for the connection string.

How can I leave the code as it is, and have it work in Azure too? I've tried setting the Application Settings in the portal, both the Connection Strings and the App Settings. And using both "SQLCONNSTR_DefaultConnection" and "Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString" as the key.

(Setting the App Settings doesn't seem to work by the way. I think the value I provide is too long).

So how can I provide the connection string for my Azure database to my Azure web app (ASP.NET 5), without checking it in in source control?

**Update**
My Startup.cs looks like this (see [the full file on GitHub](https://github.com/petermorlion/RedStar.Invoicing/blob/master/src/RedStar.Invoicing/Startup.cs)):

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var configuration = new Configuration()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
    {
        configuration.AddUserSecrets();
    } 

    configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = configuration;
}
```

In the `ConfigureServices` method, there is also:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSubKey("AppSettings"));
```

and, also in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
                   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]))
            .AddDbContext<InvoicesDbContext>(options => 
                   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
// So this is where I want my app in Azure to use the connection string I
// provide in the portal
```

Comment: can you share how your Startup.cs configuration entries look like?

Comment: If you have setup everything correctly, then specifying `Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString` in your azure websites should have just worked

Comment: Your sample code doesn't show how you are accessing the ConnectionString.  Where are you accessing the ConnectionString?  What is the syntax.  You can also test the environment variable locally by setting it in VS under project properties -> Debug.  This can help in troubleshooting (i.e. you are setting environment_variable name and setting name the same).

Comment: @GeraldDavis I added code on how I am accessing the connection string. I'll try the tip on the project properties.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Short answer

> I've tried setting the Application Settings in the portal, both the Connection Strings and the App Settings. And using both "SQLCONNSTR_DefaultConnection" and "Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString" as the key.

You're close.

1. Go to Azure web app > configure > connection strings.
2. Add a connection string with the name `DefaultConnection`.
3. Use `Configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString")` to access it.

## Example using `timesheet_db` instead of `DefaultConnection`

This is an example from my own timesheet application. My connection string was named `timesheet_db`. Just replace all instances of that string with `DefaultConnection` to adapt the example to your use case.

### Azure web app configuration

[image: Set Connection String]

### Azure web app service control manager

The online service control manager at https://myWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env will show the connection strings.

[image: Connection Strings]

### Startup.cs

Setup configuration settings in `Startup` so that the environmental variables overwrite the config.json.

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
public Startup()
{
    Configuration = new Configuration()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();    <----- will cascade over config.json
}
```

Configure the database in `Startup`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ProjectContext>(options =>
        {
            var connString =
                Configuration.Get("Data:timesheet_db:ConnectionString");
            options.UseSqlServer(connString);
        });
}
```

Of course, the example uses a connection string named `timesheet_db`. For you, replace all instances of it with your own connection string named `DefaultConnection` and everything will work.

Comment: This works. But what is the magic that converts "DefaultConnection" to "Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"?

Comment: The magic lives in the EnvironmentVariableConfigurationProvider,  e.g. check https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs#L91.

Comment: BTW, the convention is changing in RC2. The configuration key will be of the form `ConnectionStrings:name`.

Comment: `Configuration.Get` with that config name convention doesn't work anymore in final version. We need to use `Configuration.GetConnectionString("timesheet_db")` instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37511645/397807

Answer (score 13):

In RC2 I had to change how my connection strings were read to get them to work in Azure.  In my case I had to ensure the Azure connection string was named "DefaultConnection", and accessed by:

RC1:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "DefaultConnection": {
            "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        }
    }
}
```

Accessed by:

```
var conn = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"];
```

RC2:

```
{
  "Data": {

  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

Accessed by:

```
var conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options to set your connection string.
The default setup class get the enviroment settings from different sources.
You could set your connection string in config.production.json. or config.staging.json. See the startup class

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Setup configuration sources.
        var configuration = new Configuration()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
        {
            // This reads the configuration keys from the secret store.
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            configuration.AddUserSecrets();
        }
        configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

Comment: I know, but I don't want to add config.production.json to my publicly available GitHub repository. It is my understanding that you can specify settings and connection strings in the Azure portal (read [this](http://blog.jsinh.in/asp-net-5-configuration-microsoft-framework-configurationmodel/#.VY_8tkaEfIU)). But I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [**SlotSticky** Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495207.aspx)

Use this command in Azure PowerShell to set 2 app settings as sticky to the slot

```
Set-AzureWebsite -Name mysite -SlotStickyAppSettingNames @("myslot", "myslot2")
```

And this command to set 2 connection strings as sticky to the slot

```
Set-AzureWebsite -Name mysite -SlotStickyConnectionStringNames @("myconn", "myconn2")
```