# Using ASP.NET Core and EntityFramework 7 to update production DB with migration changes in Azure

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a complete web app working locally, and I am now working on getting it going in production. The app is currently sitting on Azure, and watching a git repo for new deployments, which is working great.

However, the app has a connection in its `appsettings.json` for a connection string, which looks like this:

```
"database": {
  "connection": "Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=Foo"
},

// In Startup()
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

// In ConfigureServices(...)
services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<FooDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["database:connection"]);
        });
```

This is fine for local testing, but now I'm ready to move to production and have some questions (couldn't find good documentation).

1. How do I use the `dnx` command line to push my changes to a production DB? Everything is tied to the DB defined by the app, statically, so it'll by default go to my local DB, always.
2. Once the DB is provisioned in Azure, do I simply need to modify my connection string in the settings on Azure for the web app, like this?

[image]

Comment: This post explains EF7 migrations with dnx. Check it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt614250.aspx

Comment: That article doesn't explain how to apply a database update to a production DB.

Comment: Are you (also) working with migrations locally?

Comment: Yes, I have two configs. One for local, one for production, with a connection string in each.

Comment: Are you using RC1 or RC2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Basics

You've said that you have two configs. One for local, one for production, with a connection string in each. In that case, if your production config is called `appsettings.production.json` you can do this:

Startup()

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

ConfigureServices(...)

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<FooDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["database:connection"]);
    });
```

appsettings.production.json

```
{
  "database": {
    "connection": "Server=tcp:yr3d5dswl.database.windows.net,1433;Database=EFMigrationDemo;User ID=mvp2015@yr3d5dswl;Password=3f4g%^BD45bcE;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
}
```

Command Line

```
dotnet ef database update -e Production
```

This will update your production database.

## Advanced

Integrate with your continuous integration. Have the migration update the live database on build by adding a `postbuild` script to your project.json. Azure will run this on each deployment.

```
"scripts": {
  "postbuild": [ "dotnet ef database update" ]
}
```

If you want to use environmental variables instead of a `appsettings.production.json` file, checkout [Setting the SQL connection string for ASP.NET 5 web app in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097933/setting-the-sql-connection-string-for-asp-net-5-web-app-in-azure). This keeps your username/password out of your git repo.

## References

- http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#scripts
- http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Comment: How would you test a production Azure SQL connection string locally? I set an environment variable of `set database:connection=my_production_connection_string` and my `Configuration.Get<string>("database:connection")` fails to find any environment variable. If I inspect the environment variables, I see one with this though: `Data:database:connection:ConnectionString`. with the same value that I just set for `database:connection`. Why is it transformed like that? And how can I possibly access that from my code while still allowing my `Development` environment to work too?

Comment: What method are you using to inspect environmental variables?

Comment: Using the IDE to debug the keys/values from the environment variable provider of the `IConfiguration` instance.

Comment: @mariocatch While I am not sure why it is transformed, it does seem related to conventions. Try accessing it with `Configuration.Get("Data:database:connection")`. Also set your `config.json` value to `"Data" : { "database" : {  "connection" : "..." } }`. There are more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097933/setting-the-sql-connection-string-for-asp-net-5-web-app-in-azure

Comment: Yep, the key looks to be to use the format `"Data": { "my_db": { "ConnectionString": "..." } }`.  I am testing how this works from Azure now and will respond back if there's an issue.

Comment: Looks like the postbuild step of `dnx ef database update` isn't running. My DB is not created with that step in there. Also, after inspecting the Kudu SCM environment variables, the connection string that I setup in my Azure Web App connection strings UI is: `SQLAZURECONNSTR_Data:my_database:ConnectionString`. So, that may be why all my connection string lookups are failing in production? Although I think the provider is supposed to trim the azure prefix off and still find/use it.

Comment: @mariocatch Hmm. Of interest. The postbuild step runs for me both locally and in Azure with continuous deployment. The postbuild needs to have an existing database - it will not create the db it will only update it. In Azure, though, I add the connection string in the app settings instead of the connection strings. It's possible to do both though I tend to prefer using app settings, because it provides more control over the name of the environmental variables (no more odd tranforms.)  I'm afraid I'm out of time this morning to look at this further. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110922/discussion-between-shaun-luttin-and-mariocatch).

Comment: @ShaunLuttin where do you actually run the `dotnet ef database update....` command from? I tried from Azure Kuzu console, but it cannot find *dotnet-ef*, I guess the tool is not published along with the application. Do you actually run that command from your local machine (taking advantage of the production conn. string anyway, I guess) ?