# publishing appsettings.json securely to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am using the SecretManager tool in aspnetcore to store a connection string during development to keep it out of source control.

This works just fine.

But now I want to publish the app to Azure.  When it publishes, there is no connection string in appsettings.json so the app cannot connect to the database.

So how am I supposed to include the connection string?

If I simple add it to appsettings.json, does it not defeat the whole purpose of using the secrets manager? As now I have put a username and password into a document which is under source control.

Is there something I am missing?  Am I supposed to FTP to the site and add it there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the SQL connection string for ASP.NET Core web app in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097933/setting-the-sql-connection-string-for-asp-net-5-web-app-in-azure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're supposed to put it in the Azure site settings. That's the preferred approach.

If your json looks like this:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Context": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=local-dev;Trusted_Connection=True"
  }
}
```

You create a connection string with the name `Context` (alternatively a setting with the key `ConnectionStrings:Context`) and enter your connection string in the apps *Application Settings* page:
[image: Azure Site Settings - Connection Strings]

Just make sure you're using environment variables in your Startup:

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks very much.